# Checking if nested JSON item exists or not

Tags: javascript, json

I've the following JSON result. I have to display onto a web page three dates with types: `onsaleDate`, `focDate`, `unlimitedDate`. These fields are "values" to the keys "date". I'm currently accessing the dates by using `dates[0].date`, `dates[1].date` and `dates[2].date`. The problem, however, is that some of the other `dates` results do not necessarily have all of the three items with types `onsaleDate`, `focDate`, `unlimitedDate`. How can I check that these three date `types` exist before I assign them to a variable for display onto the page? Do I need a conditional loop? Can I use `hasOwnProperty` for nested items?

```
"results": [
   "dates": [
       {
         "type": "onsaleDate",
         "date": "2011-10-12T00:00:00-0400"
       },
       {
         "type": "focDate",
         "date": "2011-09-12T00:00:00-0400"
       },
       {
         "type": "unlimitedDate",
         "date": "2012-12-18T00:00:00-0500"
       },
       {
         "type": "digitalPurchaseDate",
         "date": "2012-05-01T00:00:00-0400"
       }
     ]
```

Comment: what do you mean by `three` items?

Comment: @Fawzan Updated for clarification.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks I'll look at that first and see if it solves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find if a particular type exists in an object in an array, you can use `find`:

```
results.dates.find(obj => obj.type === "onsaleDate")
```

You can generalize this by writing a little function taking a particular property name, and returning a function suitable for passing to `find`:

```
function hasType(type) { 
  return function(o) { return o.type === type; };
}
```

Now you check for the presence of `onsaleDate` with

```
results.dates.find(hasType("onsaleDate"))
```

Or check for all three with

```
results.dates.find(hasType("onsaleDate")) && results.find(hasType("...
```

or, if you prefer

```
["onsaleDate", "focDate", "unlimitedDate"] . 
  every(type => results.dates.find(hasType(type)))
```

Comment: This is very, very neat solution I never thought about. Fantastic, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would deal with issue by modifying the datatype of the results:

```
results = JSON.parse(results);
var dates = {};
results.dates.forEach(obj => dates[obj.type] = obj.date);
results.dates = dates;

//now you can access them by
if(results.dates.onsaleDate){
  // display on sale date....
}
```